# Hiding a table if a search result does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, search

Exactly what the title says. I want the table containing all of the search queries to be hidden, but I've tried a lot of things and none of them work. For example, `if($myData!=null) {proceed with showing the table}`, but that didn't work. `isset()` also didn't work. Any ideas?

```
<style>
    ul
    {
        list-style-type: none;
    }

</style>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=iso-8859-1">
        <title>Search Chemicals</title>
    </head>
    <p>
    <body>
        <h3>Chemical Information</h3>
        <p>You may search by Catalog number, CASRN, or the chemical name.</p>
        <form  method="post" action="search.php?go"  id="searchform">
            <input  type="text" name="name">
            <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
        <?php
        error_reporting(0);

        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            if (isset($_GET['go'])) {
                if (preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", $_POST['name'])) {
                    $name   = $_POST['name'];
                    $conn   = mysql_connect("localhost", "Blimeo", "password");
                    $db     = mysql_connect("localhost", "-", "-") or die('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
                    //-select  the database to use
                    $mydb   = mysql_select_db("chemicals");
                    //-query  the database table
                    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE Catalog LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR CASRN LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR Chemical_Name LIKE '%" . $name . "%'";
                    $myData = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
                    echo "<table border=1>
            <tr>
            <th>Catalog</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>CASRN</th>
            <th>Chemical Name</th>
            <th>Quantity 1</th>
            <th>Price 1</th>
            <th>Quantity 2</th>
            <th>Price 2</th>
            <th>Quantity 3</th>
            <th>Price 3</th>
            <th>Quantity 4</th>
            <th>Price 4</th>
            </tr>";
                    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) {

                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['Catalog'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td><img src=\"./img/" . $record['Image'] . "\" alt=\"Chemical\"/></td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['CASRN'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['Chemical_Name'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['Quantity1'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['Price1'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['Quantity2'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['Price2'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['Quantity3'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['Price3'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['Quantity4'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $record['Price4'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                        echo "</form>";
                        echo "<ul>\n";
                        echo "<li>" . "<a  href=\"search.php?id=$ID\">" . $Catalog . " " . $CASRN . " " . $Chemical_Name . "</a></li>\n";
                        echo "</ul>";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p>Product not found! Please rephrase your search criteria.</p>";
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
</p>
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql_/).

Comment: Try `mysql_num_rows()`. If it's > 0, display the table. `mysqli` and `PDO` both have similar functions.

Answer (score 1):

You should add [`mysql_num_rows();`](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows)

```
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$exists = mysql_num_rows($myData);
if($exists) {
    echo "<table border=1>";
    //..................
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Product not found! Please rephrase your search criteria.</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you are echoing out your table regardless of the results of the search query.  You should probably check the number of rows returned in teh result set and only echo out the table if the count is > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div visibility="hidden">` to hide the table and use Javascript to change the visibility based on the search queries or some other condition.